# SCSS Height Property will not Convert to CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am creating a simple website, using Ruby SCSS to CSS, and have run into one of those head-slam-wall moments. My `article` element needs a `height: 100%;` value in order to have a scrollbar. I can add this into the `.css` or Chrome dev tools just fine and voila, it's fixed.

The problem, though, is that whenever I save and SCSS compiles to CSS, it purposefully excludes the `height: 100%;`, as if to mock me. I'd prefer to not have to go to the CSS and add the line back each time I compile my SCSS -- does anyone know this bug or have a hint as to what tools I could use to find out what this stems from?

The SCSS in Question:

```
.modalElement {
    position: relative;

    @mixin articleExpand {
        height: 100%;
        top: 0%;
        border-radius: 0;
        width: 100%;

        header {
            height: 20%;
            overflow: auto;
        } 

        .articleContent {
            height: 80%;
        }
    }
    ... (more unrelated SCSS)
}
...
&.articleExpanded {
    &.modalElementArticle article {
        @include articleExpand;
    } 
}
```

The Generated CSS in Question:

```
.modalElement.articleExpanded.modalElementArticle article {
  top: 0%;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The (Simplified) HTML:

```
<figure class="modalElement modalElementArticle flipper articleCard articleExpanded">
            <div class="flipperContainer">
                <div class="flipperFront">
                <button class="modalElementMain flipperFrontContent imgCenteredContainer modalGroup">

                    <article>
                        <header>
                            <h2 class="">Flower</h2>
                            <h3 class="">Why do we love flowers...</h3>
                        </header>
                        <div class="articleContent"> <div class="breakClear"></div></div>
                        <div class="articleMarkdown hide"></div>
                    </article>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="flipperBack">

                </div>
            </div>
        </figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the mixin out of class

```
.modalElement {
    position: relative;

    ... (more unrelated SCSS)
}

@mixin articleExpand {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;

    header {
        height: 20%;
        overflow: auto;
    } 

    .articleContent {
        height: 80%;
    }
}

...
&.articleExpanded {
    &.modalElementArticle article {
        @include articleExpand;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Simultaneously hate and love that it was so simple. Do you know per chance why that's the case? The width and other properties were still affecting it, just the not the height.

Comment: I can't tell you why. I just checked your code in [here](https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/) and it was not valid. If you ever get the reason feel free to comment.